# Do we have StorageClass creation function in pykube?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-storage, kubectl

I am using various functions from pykube for creating namespaces, pods, rc, services, etc I am able to create those, however, one of my deployment processes has StorageClass to create.

I checked the pykube object, it doesn't have the StorageClass functions, any other ways for creating StorageClass?
https://github.com/kelproject/pykube/blob/master/pykube/objects.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using pykube I switched to kubernetes python module, where I can easily create StorageClass.

```
pip install kubernetes
```

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/StorageV1Api.md[enter link description here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/StorageV1Api.md)